# Python data wrangling issues

Tags: python, pandas, unique, dataframe

I'm currently stumped by some basic issues with a small data set. Here are the first three lines to illustrate the format of the data:

"Sport","Entry","Contest_Date_EST","Place","Points","Winnings_Non_Ticket","Winnings_Ticket","Contest_Entries","Entry_Fee","Prize_Pool","Places_Paid"

"NBA","NBA 3K Crossover #3 [3,000 Guaranteed] (Early Only) (1/15)","2015-03-01 13:00:00",35,283.25,"13.33","0.00",171,"20.00","3,000.00",35

"NBA","NBA 1,500 Layup #4 [1,500 Guaranteed] (Early Only) (1/25)","2015-03-01 13:00:00",148,283.25,"3.00","0.00",862,"2.00","1,500.00",200

The issues I am having after using read_csv to create a DataFrame:

1. The presence of commas in certain categorical values (such as Prize_Pool) results in python considering these entries as strings. I need to convert these to floats in order to make certain calculations. I've used python's replace() function to get rid of the commas, but that's as far as I've gotten.
2. The category Contest_Date_EST contains timestamps, but some are repeated. I'd like to subset the entire dataset into one that has only unique timestamps. It would be nice to have a choice in which repeated entry or entries are removed, but at the moment I'd just like to be able to filter the data with unique timestamps.

Comment: No, *all* fields are considered strings by `csv`. If you want them to not be strings then you need to postprocess them.

Comment: Ok good to know, but python allowed me to make basic calculations on other categories (such as Entry_Fee) with no issues. What kind of post-processing would you recommend?

Comment: Then something else is postprocessing those fields. Perhaps you should tell it the right way to postprocess the other fields.

Comment: Whats wrong with i.e. `float(row[9].replace(',',''))` ?

Comment: Ok, what about filtering out repeated  entries from the timestamp category?

Re: Clemens - I get the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `thousands=','` argument for numbers that contain a comma

```
In [1]: from pandas import read_csv
In [2]: d = read_csv('data.csv', thousands=',')
```

You can check Prize_Pool is numerical

```
In [3]: type(d.ix[0, 'Prize_Pool'])
Out[3]: numpy.float64
```

To drop rows - take first observed, you can also take last

```
In [7]: d.drop_duplicates('Contest_Date_EST', take_last=False)
Out[7]:
  Sport                                              Entry  \
0   NBA  NBA 3K Crossover #3 [3,000 Guaranteed] (Early ...

      Contest_Date_EST  Place  Points  Winnings_Non_Ticket  Winnings_Ticket  \
0  2015-03-01 13:00:00     35  283.25                13.33                0

   Contest_Entries  Entry_Fee  Prize_Pool  Places_Paid
0              171         20        3000           35
```

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: Just realized you're using pandas - should have looked at that.
>   I'll leave this here for now in case it's applicable but if it gets
>   downvoted I'll take it down by virtue of peer pressure :)
>
> I'll try and update it to use pandas later tonight

Seems like `itertools.groupby()` is the tool for this job;

Something like this?

```
import csv
import itertools

class CsvImport():

    def Run(self, filename):
        # Get the formatted rows from CSV file
        rows = self.readCsv(filename)
        for key in rows.keys():
            print "\nKey: " + key
            i = 1
            for value in rows[key]:
                print "\nValue {index} : {value}".format(index = i, value = value)
                i += 1

    def readCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'rU') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            # Keys may or may not be pulled in with extra space by DictReader()
            # The next line simply creates a small dict of stripped keys to original padded keys
            keys = { key.strip(): key for (key) in reader.fieldnames }
            # Format each row into the final string
            groupedRows = {}
            for k, g in itertools.groupby(reader, lambda x : x["Contest_Date_EST"]):
                groupedRows[k] = [self.normalizeRow(v.values()) for v in g]
            return groupedRows;

    def normalizeRow(self, row):
        row[1] = float(row[1].replace(',','')) # "Prize_Pool"
        # and so on
        return row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CsvImport().Run("./Test1.csv")
```

Output:
[image]

More info:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Hope this helps :)